# Strongly-typed generic method invokes its argument's base class method, instead of a shadowed method in T?

Tags: vb.net, generics, strong-typing, shadowing

Consider a `MyForm` class that contains a shadowed implementation of `Show()`. It also contains a `CreateForm()` method, which accepts an instance of the form and calls the shadowed sub:

```
Public Class MyForm
    Inherits Form

    Public Shadows Sub Show()
        MessageBox.Show("Shadowed implementation called!")
    End Sub
End Class

...

Public Sub CreateForm(ByVal childForm As MyForm)
    childForm.MdiParent = Me
    childForm.Show()
    childForm.Focus()
End Sub
```

When called with `CreateForm(New MyForm())`, the shadowed implementation of `Show()` is correctly called. Now consider the following generic implementation:

```
Public Sub CreateForm(Of T As Form)(ByVal childForm As T)
    childForm.MdiParent = Me
    childForm.Show()
    childForm.Focus()
End Sub
```

Called with `CreateForm(Of MyForm)(New MyForm())`, this strongly-typed generic method never invokes the shadowed method.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is "By Design".  The trick to remember here is that the generic method is compiled and verified by itself (not in the context of the caller as is done in C++).  Hence the generic method only knows that `T` is related to `Form`.  It has no knowledge of `MyForm` and hence correctly binds to methods on `Form`.

This is correct because `Shadows` methods only come into play with the type of the reference at compile time makes the `Shadow` method visible.  This is not the case here as the reference type at compile type is `Form` (not `MyForm)`.  This is in contrast to `Overridable` where the behavior changes based on the runtime type.

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm still not understanding how/why the context of the caller has no bearing on the argument type. Wouldn't that mean that a generic defined like `SomeMethod(Of T)(ByVal arg As T)` would always have an argument of type `Object`?

Comment: @Rob, from the perspective of binding methods on `arg`, yes it is essentially considered to be `Object`.  This line is blurred a bit in VB.Net though as by default option strict is disabled and late binding would occur for non-Object methods.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing something. It only knows that it is dealing with a Form at compile-time (remember that generics are not templates!). The only thing you can do is use (override) virtual methods instead of shadowing them.

See also ['Shadows' vs. 'Overrides' in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463209/shadows-vs-overrides-in-vb-net) for more info on shadowing - that's not actually polymorphism.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that a generic defined like `SomeMethod(Of T)(ByVal arg As T)` would always have an argument of type `Object`?  My call to the generic method explicitly states the type as `MyForm`, so I thought the compiler should be able to infer the argument type. In fact, that seems to be the normal behavior...?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug because the call is evaluated by the compiler *statically* based just on the given type constraints applied to `T`, that is `Form`. The compiler cannot predict the actual type could contain a shadowed method declaration or whatever other method not declared in the known parent (i.e. `Form`).