# How to modify .net's BackgroundWorker class so that it fires a custom event upon method completion

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker in a vb.net program that is doing a lengthy data import routine. I want to modify its RunWorkerAsync method so that it fires a custom event on completion of the method. (So that a method in an automated process can respond to the event and resume its work).  In a sense I want to 'extend' the RunWorkerAsync method to add an extra line of code--but I can't 'see' the code in the method (to just add the line raising the event) because BackgroundWorker is an MSDN class from Microsoft.

The only solution that I can think of is to 'wrap' the background worker class in a wrapper that calls the .RunWorkerAsync method and then raises the event.

```
Public sub wrapperMethod()
    myBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    raise customEvent
end sub
```

Is there a design pattern that I might use? An easy way to address this with the .net language?

PS: Unfortunately, I'm automating some clanking legacy software and backgroundworker is used in many locations, so wrapping the backgroundworker will be a bit of work and may open bugs.

Comment: can you override the base "RunWorkerAsync" method with your own, that raises your own event as well as calling MyBase.RunWorkerAsync - or if the "RunWorkerAsync" method isn't marked as Overridable use Shadows instead. See here for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463209/shadows-vs-overrides-in-vb-net

Comment: I don't think either will work. A shadow would hide the .RunWorkerAsync() method (so I would not be able to start a background thread). A child class with an override method will either keep the parent's RunWorkerAsync() method as is (which would not help) or replace/hide the method (which would again mean I would not be able to easily create a background thread)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"In a sense I want to 'extend' the RunWorkerAsync method to add an extra line of code"**

Tap into the RunWorkerComplete event and use that as your "raise customEvent", here is an example on MSDN:

[Background Worker RunWorkerCompleted event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx)

Comment: +1. BackgroundWorker already does what the OP wants, no need to change it at all.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I did not know about that event. Exactly what I needed.