# Difference between C# new and override keyword on property

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-overflow

I've got an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) usercontrol with a panel that I'm using to hide and show the content, that is,

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID=pnlContainer">
    <!-- Some fairly uninteresting content -->
</asp:Panel>
```

I've got a visible property as an overrider, that is,

```
    public override bool Visible 
    {
        get { return pnlContainer.Visible; }
        set { pnlContainer.Visible = value;  } 
    }
```

When I set it I get a stack overflow exception BUT when I change the keyword to `new`, that is,

```
    public new bool Visible 
    {
        get { return pnlContainer.Visible; }
        set { pnlContainer.Visible = value;  } 
    }
```

Everything works fine. Why is this? I think I've just got a generally poor understanding of these keywords and it's showing here.

Also:

If I put no keyword on - Visual Studio gives a warning saying that either the `new` or the `override` keyword should be used as I am masking an already existing member on the user control.

In a way, my strange practice of using a panel to control the visible on the user control isn't the issue here. With help of the contributors it's clearly mad and shouldn't be done. But the issue that interested me was that the `override` and `new` keywords behaved in such different ways and the reasons for this.

Comment: It looks like you're overriding the Panel Containers implimentation of the Visible property, and setting it inside itself is causing an infinate loop.

Comment: What's `pnlContainer` (i.e. is it a member variable of some sort)?

Comment: No the panel container is in a user control. Won't the user control be the naming container in this case?

Comment: Does this specifically happen only when you use the `set` method, and not the `get` method?

Comment: It depends on where you are defining the property, but my guess is that you are overriding the Visible property for something that already has a Visible property.  Is this in a custom control or something?

Comment: @CrabBucket how does your class declaration look like? And what's the type of your pnlContainer?

Comment: OK so the intended functionality, when dealing with an implementation of the User Control, is instead of its Visible property making the `ControlAdapter` visible/invisible (the default), you want to override that behavior and instead make its member `Panel` visible/invisible.  Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry everyone - wasnt clear. This is in a user control. Visual Studio wants a keyword because of a pre-exisitng member. I just don't see why override causes the overflow and new doesn't. I was just doing on set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is summarized on the Microsoft page *[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.)*.

Review the section of code indicated there. It is also listed below:

```
public static void TestCars2()
{
    Car[] cars = new Car[3];
    cars[0] = new Car();
    cars[1] = new ConvertibleCar();
    cars[2] = new Minivan();
}

foreach (Car vehicle in cars)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Car object: " + vehicle.GetType());
    vehicle.DescribeCar();
    System.Console.WriteLine("----------");
}
```

The same principle is getting applied to your source. The .NET framework treats all controls on the page as a collection of base Control classes. `Control.Visible` is a virtual property.

This means: when the ASP.NET framework invokes `Control.Visible` for all controls, the only `Control.Visible` property that is invoked from your source is the one marked as `override`, which is what people typically think of with standard polymorphism. Otherwise, if you declare your property as `new`, when the ASP.NET framework invokes `Control.Visible`, your property is never called.

Thus the override results in a stack overflow exception since you are then calling your `panel.Visible`, which is recursively calling itself many times.

Comment: Is there a way that .Visible can be overridden for only the .Visible property of the User Control?  Or does specifying `new` effectively do that?  Just curious.

Comment: That's sort of what the new keyword does. It overrides the property just for the user control. I find it a bit dangerous to use the new keyword in general though. You can run into many issues down the road as exhibited by the hoardes of stackoverflow.com posts related to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword hides an inherited member (see *[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)* for an example).

So when you apply `new` in this case, at some point the object is then being referenced as its base class, and the base class setter is being called instead of your derived class setter (which has an infinite loop because your setter calls itself).